# How to change terminal font color in Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, fonts

I cannot find a way to tweak the terminal font colour in Eclipse. It is appearing in horrible pink :(

Looks like there is no straightforward config to change this setting in Eclipse. Any hacky way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Install the [TM Terminal](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal#group-details) plugin of Eclipse.
2. Go to `Window` select `Preferences`
3. Click on `Terminal`
4. Check the box `Invert terminal colors`
5. Click `Apply`

Comment: This app comes installed by default. Inverting color still keeps it pink only background is changed.